# How to select multiple in select list without using Shift+Click

Tags: html, angular

I am using a `<select>` tag on my angular app. I have set it up so you can select more than option. But you can only select options when you <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left Click</kbd>. I want to be able to select multiple options by only <kbd>Left Click</kbd>.

The `<select>` tag is set up like:

```
<select multiple>
  <option>Option One</option>
  <option>Option Two</option>
  <option>Option Three</option>
</select>
```

I saw something like what I wanted to achieve using [Material](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) but I cannot use material within the form that I have set up.

Is there a way to achieve multiple select just from a mouse click and now having to press shift?

Comment: you can use Angular Multiselect Dropdown to convert the normal multi-select to dropdown with multiselect . Check [ng-multiselect-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown)

Comment: Use javascript to set the option tags to selected.

Answer (score 1):

Not in plain html. But a event listener or onclick handler in plain javascript can do the trick. Very basic and rough just to give you a idea.

```
<script>
    function select(id){
     var opt=document.getElementById(id);
     opt.selected=!opt.selected ;
    }
</script>

<select multiple>
 <option id="o1" onclick="select('o1')">Option 1</option>
 <option id="o2" onclick="select('o2')">Option 2</option>
 <option id="o3" onclick="select('o3')">Option 3</option>
</select>
```